# Displaying thumbnail images horizontally in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a small issue i'm able to display images in the form thumbnails horizontally. These thumbnails behaves like a button. So when the user clicks any image then my images are not displaying horizontally there positions are changes after clicking.

Here is my html code

```
<div class="thumbnailDiv">  
    <img src="/Ecm/HelloWorld0.png" width="80px" height="100px" style="margin-left: 20px;" onclick='displayPdfImage("image")/>              
</div>
```

Here is my css code

```
.thumbnailDiv {
    white-space: nowrap;
    float: left;
    display:inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height:100px;
    overflow-x:auto;
    background-color:  #C2DFFF;
 }
```

Whenever the image is clicked then a java script function is called

Here is the java script function

```
function displayPdfImage(img) {
    $("#dropdiv object").remove();
    $("#dropdiv img").remove();
    $("#dropdiv input").remove();
    $("#dropdiv").append(
        "<img src='/Ecm/Temp/HelloWorld"+img+".png' style='z-index:-1;width:800px;height:720px;'/>");
    $("#dropdiv").append(
        "<input  type='submit' value='SAVE' style='position:absolute; top: 670px; left:900px; z-index:10;' onclick='saveBothImages("+ img + ");'/>");
    document.getElementById(img).style.display = 'block';
}
```

my thumbnail images positions are getting changed when i click the image but not initially.hope u have understood my problem..

please help me

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Could you create fiddle for this. As from above code your problem is not clear

Comment: Not fully clear on what the exact problem is here, but when looking at the call onclick='displayPdfImage("image") on the HTML, it seems like you are always passing the same input "image" to the function, which is puzzling.

Comment: Are you trying to append images horizontally on the element #dropdiv?

Comment: As Virita and Kyo imply, there is more to this problem but not enough of your code and HTML yet. Also you have an unnecessary mix of raw DOM access with jQuery. If you use jQuery, use it for the style setting as well e.g. $('#'+img).css({display: "block"});

Comment: @Kyo just to explain my code i have used "image".actually those images are created dynamically from a pdf file where each pdf page is converted into pdf image and displayed as thumbnails horizontally.so if the user want to see the any of the pdf page he should click on the thumbnail image and that particular pdf page image is displayed

Comment: @VinitaRathore can u please tell me what u couldnt understand from above???

Comment: @Kyo i'm appending the bigger size image of thumbnail which the user clicked to see to #dropdiv

Comment: And your issue is that the thumbnails images are changing positions when clicked? The code above indicates nothing about the movement of the thumbnails. In other words, some other functions must be influencing the positions of the thumbnail images.

Comment: @Kyo yes exactly i know that but i wanted to know where is the problem related to is it in the :displayPdfImage()" or any other problem

Comment: Even screenshots of the problem would help if you can't provide a JSFiddle. Otherwise it will be a case of *down-vote and move on* as it is not clear what the problem is. Thanks.

Comment: Notice that the displayPdfImage() is only dealing with the element "#dropdiv". If "#dropdiv" is part of the div "thumbnailDiv", then yes, it might shuffle things around as items get attached and removed. If not, I would suggest remove the line document.getElementById(img).style.display = 'block'; since we do not know what "img" values are for this function, based on the code above.

Comment: @Kyo i works perfectly now thanx allot dude.it works perfectly after removing document.getElementById(img).style.display = 'block'; thank you soo much dude...